# Gallery's images lose their proportion after deleting an image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a gallery. When I delete one image, the images coming after the deleted image lose their proportions.[image: Before deletion]

If I delete the ice cream image, for example, the gallery turns out to be like this:
[image: After deletion]
Render function looks like this:

```
  deleteImage = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      imageUrlArray: this.state.imageUrlArray.filter((url) => url !== this.state.popImageUrl)
    })
  }

  onImgLoad = ({target:img}) => {
  let aspectRatio = img.offsetWidth/img.offsetHeight;
  img.style.width = aspectRatio*200 + "px";
  img.style.flexGrow = aspectRatio*200; 
}

    render() {
    let imageUrlArray = this.state.imageUrlArray;
    
    const images = imageUrlArray.map((url, index) =>{
    return(
          <img
            src={url} 
            alt="imageItem"
            onClick={() => this.handlePopup(url)}
            onLoad={this.onImgLoad}
            key={index}
          />
      )
    })
    return (
      <div className="root" onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter} onDragOver={this.onDragOver} onDrop={this.onDrop}>
        <section>
          {this.state.showModal && (
          <Popup
          deleteImage={this.deleteImage}
          popImageUrl={this.state.popImageUrl}
          closePopup={this.handlePopup}
          />)}
          {images} 
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

NOTE: All the proportions are calculated in onImgLoad function.

SOLUTION: `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` did the job. But I would appreciate if someone could explain why the offsetHeight and offsetWidth change after deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the page after deleting the image because next image to deleted image  gets the coordinated and size from that deleted image.

Comment: Images are not saved anywhere. Everything will just get to the initial state.